# Qt Doesn't Seem to Include MinGW Includes

Tags: c++, windows, qt, command-line, mingw

My problem today is in compiling a QT application from the command line on Windows using Qt 5.1.0 with MinGW. My Qt installation is at `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0-MinGW`.

It compiles fine in Qt Creator, but from the command line it seems to not include headers from `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0-MinGW\Tools\mingw48_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include`, which I `#include` in some of my code.

For example, I `#include <Ws2tcpip.h>`, which is in `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0-MinGW\Tools\mingw48_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include`, in one of my C++ files, and then I use the function `getaddrinfo`, which is declared in `Ws2tcpip.h`.

This compiles just fine in Qt Creator, but compiling from the command line I get `error: 'getaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope`.

This is just one example, and I have a couple of others where things defined in header files residing in the `i686-w64-mingw32/include` folder seem to not be defined when compiling on the command line.

Why would it compile any differently between Qt Creator and the command line, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `C:/Qt/Qt5.1.0-MinGW/5.1.0/mingw48_32/bin;C:/Qt/Qt5.1.0-MinGW/Tools/mingw48_32/bin` to the beginning of the `PATH` environment variable.

(I realized later that invoking `C:/Qt/Qt5.1.0-MinGW/5.1.0/mingw48_32/bin/qtenv2.bat` did exactly this. I just didn't know about this script at the time.)

In addition, I added `-r -spec win32-g++` to my `qmake` command, which is immediately before `mingw32-make`.

Answer (score 0):

Locks that you did not setup your environment correctly. Just take a look at your project-kit settings in QtCreator (build environment) as a reference.

Comment: I did, but saw nothing unusual. What should I be looking for?